# SQL: Multiple IF's examining the same varible

Tags: if-statement, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say we have two variables in a SQL statement.

```
@myVar1 VARCHAR(100) = 'I ate an apple for lunch'
@myVar2 INT
```

Now, I want the following logic:

```
IF @myVar1 like '%apple%' THEN @myVar2 = 1
IF @myVar1 like '%orange%' THEN @myVar2 = 2
IF @myVar1 like '%banana%' THEN @myVar2 = 3
IF @myVar1 like '%kiwi%' THEN @myVar2 = 4
IF @myVar1 like '%pineapple%' THEN @myVar2 = 5
```

This is outside of any select statement.  I just need to examine a passed in string, and set an integer according to an expected sub-string.  There would be a finite list of possible values for @myVar1, and they are all known.

I just need help with the T-SQL syntax. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? You can't use `SELECT CASE @myVar1` since you're using `LIKE` so any improvement would be minor.  What if the `@myVar1` was `apples and bananas are different shapes`?

Comment: The fruit is just a substitute in this example to keep things simple.  There would be a finite list of possible values for @myVar1, and they are all known.  I just need help with the t-sql syntax.

Comment: Then why use `like`?  If you use `=` then you can use a `CASE` statement which would be a _little_ cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CASE` as following:

```
DECLARE @myVar1 VARCHAR(100) = 'I ate an apple for lunch'
DECLARE @myVar2 INT

SET @myVar2 = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @myVar1 LIKE '%apple%'     THEN 1
        WHEN @myVar1 LIKE '%orange%'    THEN 2
        WHEN @myVar1 LIKE '%banana%'    THEN 3
        WHEN @myVar1 LIKE '%kiwi%'      THEN 4
        WHEN @myVar1 LIKE '%pineapple%' THEN 5
    END
```

Comment: @CaseyCrookston You accepted this answer because it solves your problem. That's absolutely up to you, but: You really should not use hardcoded values unless this is just a tiny private *just-for-fun* thing...

Comment: I understand.  I really do.  However, the entire picture is very different than what I posted here.  I just used a simple example because I was hoping people would not second guess my purposes and try and make the answer more complex than what I needed.  All I needed was a little nudge towards the right syntax, which is why I asked the question how I did.  I already know how to build a key value table and do a lookup from it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with the pattern as the key and the integer value as another column. Then you can write

```
SELECT @MyVar2 = IntCol
  FROM TheTable
 WHERE @MyVar1 LIKE PatternCol
```

Now you can manage the table contents and not have to edit code.

Comment: I understand that it's better to store these keys in a table.  I get it.  But for the sake of what I'm trying to accomplish, I'd like some help in just getting to the syntax, as asked!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to store data into tables, not within SQL code. In your case that means storing mappings between patterns and values similar to this:

### FruitValue

```
FruitValueId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
Token VARCHAR(32),
Value INT
```

Inserted values should be like the following:

('apple', 1), ('orange', 2) and so on

From your example, it is not clear what happens if multiple fruits appear in one sentence, but for the simple example of one fruit per sentence, the following query could be used (adapt to the actual used SQL flavor):

```
SELECT TOP 1 @myVar2 = Value
FROM FruitValue 
WHERE @myVar1 LIKE '%' + Token + '%'
```

Comment: I understand that it's better to store these keys in a table.  I get it.  But for the sake of what I'm trying to accomplish, I'd like some help in just getting to the syntax, as asked!

Comment: What is the SQL flavor you are using?

Comment: ms sql 2008 r2.  Good question

Comment: The final query should work fine in T-SQL. I would have a clear separation between the PK (FruitValueId) and its value, if you want the freedom to assign the values as you want.

Comment: @Alexei You are right about the separation of key and value. One should not use the PK in any meaningful way. We just don't know, what the OP wants to do with this...

Answer (score 0):

What about a catalog-table?

```
CREATE TABLE Fruits(ID INT IDENTITY, FruitName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Fruits VALUES
 ('Apple'),('Orange'),('Banana'),('Kiwi'),('Pineapple');

DECLARE @myVar1 VARCHAR(100)='I ate an apple for lunch';
DECLARE @myVar2 INT=(SELECT ID FROM Fruits WHERE @myVar1 LIKE '%' + FruitName + '%');

SELECT @myVar2;

--If there might be more than one:
SELECT *
FROM Fruits
WHERE @myVar1 LIKE '%' + FruitName + '%';

DROP TABLE Fruits
```

Comment: I understand that it's better to store these keys in a table. I get it. But for the sake of what I'm trying to accomplish, I'd like some help in just getting to the syntax, as asked!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston But this is the syntax, isn't it? If you are sure, that there is just one possible result, you might use the `=(SELECT ID FROM Fruits WHERE @myVar1 LIKE '%' + FruitName + '%')`. If there might be multiple results you should use the `SELECT * FROM Fruits WHERE ...` What is unclear?

Comment: I didn't want a table.  I just wanted a simple CASE statement, but I was having trouble with the syntax.  Siyavash Hamdi posted the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, sorry... Now I understand what you wanted. I took your comments below mine and other answers exactly the opposite way... Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

you could also try this

```
declare 
@myVar1 VARCHAR(100) = 'I ate an apple for lunch',
@myVar2 INT


IF @myVar1 like '%apple%' set @myVar2 = 1 else 
IF @myVar1 like '%orange%' set @myVar2 = 2 else
IF @myVar1 like '%banana%' set @myVar2 = 3 else
IF @myVar1 like '%kiwi%' set @myVar2 = 4 else
IF @myVar1 like '%pineapple%' set @myVar2 = 5



select @myVar2
```